# GoogleMaps getCurrentLocation does not respond

Tags: javascript

I want to get the currentUserPosition via this method calls:

```
 getCurrentUserLocation(function(location) {
     console.log(location);
 }.bind(this));


function getCurrentUserLocation(callback) {
    if (navigator.geolocation) {
        browserSupportFlag = true;
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
      initialLocation = new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude);
        map.setCenter(initialLocation);
        callback(initialLocation);
    }, function() {
        handleNoGeoLocation(browserSupportFlag);
    });
} else {
    browserSupportFlag = false;
    handleNoGeoLocation(browserSupportFlag);
}

function handleNoGeoLocation(errorFlag) {
    if (errorFlag == true) {
        alert("Geolocation service failed.");
    } else {
        alert("Your browser doesn't support geolocation");
    }
}
```

But the `console.log` does not return a value. So I think I handle the callbacks in a wrong way? it is logging:

```
_.M {}lat: ()arguments: (...)caller: (...)length: 0name: ""prototype: Object__proto__: ()<function scope>lng: ()arguments: (...)caller: (...)length: 0name: ""prototype: Object__proto__: ()<function scope>__proto__: Object
```

https://jsfiddle.net/02ezncwk/

I thought by using `callback(initialLocation)` I would hand over the output of the one handler to the encompassing one?

Comment: What does it log? `undefined`? Can you create a Fiddle or something?

Comment: hi Putvande. I just added the log output

Comment: Maybe it is because of the `.bind(this)`?

Comment: oh wait.. actually..no. I need this .bind to get access to a variable outside of the scope of the function in another script. The question would be: Do I use my callback handler correctly?